# Add a second IP to SPF record, from an external SMTP server

Tags: smtp, spam, spf

I would like to add the IP of an external SMTP server to an existing SPF record, which is looks like this:

```
"v=spf1 a mx ip4:185.6.139.6 a:frey.mailpool.1.netmask.hu a:frey.mailpool.2.netmask.hu a:frey.mailpool.3.netmask.hu ~all"
```

Isn't will it mess up the parts with the "a:frey....." syntaxes, while the current and the new IP belongs to different servers? This would be the most simple way, but it looks too easy:

```
"v=spf1 a mx ip4:91.82.220.135 ip4:185.6.139.6 a:frey.mailpool.1.netmask.hu a:frey.mailpool.2.netmask.hu a:frey.mailpool.3.netmask.hu ~all"
```

Thank you

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: Is there an actual issue here? No, there's nothing wrong with `ip4` and `a` parts coexisting in an SPF record. http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html parses your proposed record just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The record, without evaluating for correct IP addresses and URLs, is valid. The only limit I am aware of for SPF is exceeding the maximum string length of a DNS TXT record, which is 255 characters.

[RFC 4408](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4408) does give some additional guidelines:

> 3.1.4.  Record Size
>
> The published SPF record for a given domain name SHOULD remain
>   small enough that the results of a query for it will fit within 512
>   octets. This will keep even older DNS implementations from falling
>   over to TCP. Since the answer size is dependent on many things
>   outside the scope of this document, it is only possible to give
>   this guideline: If the combined length of the DNS name and the text
>   of all the records of a given type (TXT or SPF) is under 450
>   characters, then DNS answers should fit in UDP packets. Note that
>   when computing the sizes for queries of the TXT format, one must
>   take into account any other TXT records published at the domain
>   name.  Records that are too long to fit in a single UDP packet MAY
>   be silently ignored by SPF clients.

You may also want to read through the [SPF Record Syntax](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax) and to better understand available mechanisms and what they do.